# sql server get concatenated values of two diferrent column data types

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Need your expert help in building sql query for concatenated values of two different column data types( first is date & second column is int)

`select (LOCKER.AGRMNT_DATE + cast(LOCKER.AGRMNT_MTHS as varchar)) as AGRMNT_DUE_DATE from tableName`

This is throwing an error:

`Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_sample, Line 52
The data types date and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.`

Comment: Try converting both columns to the `varchar` type. You are nearly there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select (CAST(LOCKER.AGRMNT_DATE AS VARCHAR) + cast(LOCKERREG.AGRMNT_MTHS as varchar)) as AGRMNT_DUE_DATE from tableName
```

Simple test:

```
DECLARE @testDate DATE = GETDATE();
DECLARE @testInt INT = 1;
SELECT CAST(@testDate AS VARCHAR) + CAST(@testInt AS VARCHAR);
```

Output:
2015-02-161

Comment: HI sid, Thanks & it works for concatenating. And in addition to this if  I would like to show the output as current Date + 1 month so final output should be agrmt_due_date : 2015-03-16. month should get added to the current month. Pls help building this as well.  Thanks again...

Comment: DECLARE @testDate DATE = GETDATE();
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @testDate);

Comment: Hi sid, based on  I made your input I made my final query like this   select (cast(LOCKER.AGRMNT_DATE as varchar) + dateadd(month,cast(LOCKER.AGRMNT_MTHS as int),'mm-dd-yyyy')) as AGRMNT_DUE_DATE from tableName   but seems not working ... pls help me in this way to achive the same so that my output should be 2015-03-16 instead of Output: 2015-02-161

Comment: select dateadd(month,cast(LOCKER.AGRMNT_MTHS as int),LOCKER.AGRMNT_DATE) as AGRMNT_DUE_DATE from tableName